# Mongoose | populate an array of ref documents of a collection that is also an embedded collection of another collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

```
const schemaA = new mongoose.Schema({
    Cs: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "ModelC"}]
});
const ModelA = mongoose.model("ModelA", schemaA);



const schemaB = new mongoose.Schema({
    Cs: [schemaC]
});
const ModelB = mongoose.model("ModelB", schemaB);



const schemaC = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    As: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "ModelA"}]
});
const ModelC = mongoose.model("ModelC", schemaC);
```

Let's say I try to remove a ModelA document that "points" to several ModelC documents through array path "Cs" but right before the removal, I would like to use a `pre` middleware to go through each ModelC document of the "Cs" array and update their "As" array so that they don't point to the removed ModelC anymore.

```
schemaA.pre("remove", { query: true, document: false }, async function (next) {
    const a = await this.model
        .findOne(this.getQuery())
        .populate("Cs");
        
    a.Cs.forEach((c) => {
        // Update each `c.As` to no longer have a ref to the removed ModelA 
        // Problem is a.Cs is an empty MongooseArray
    });
}
```

Before calling the `populate` function, a.Cs is an array of _ids.
The problem is that `a.Cs` is an empty array when I try to populate "Cs".

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to call `exec()` when populating:

```
const a = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery()).populate("Cs").exec()
```

Comment: That didn't make a difference, unfortunately.